# Anchor id tag to bring section to a desired position

Tags: css, anchor

```
<div id="nav_bar" style="position: fixed; height: 200px; z-index: 9999;">Navigation Bar</div>
<ul>
<li><a href"#1">A Section</a><li>
<li><a href"#2">B Section</a><li>
<li><a href"#3">C Section</a><li>
<ul>

<ul>
<li><a id="1">A Section</a></li>
<li><a id="2">B Section</a></li>
<li><a id="3">C Section</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I click the anchor tag, the target section goes underneath the navigation bar. Is there anyway I can have it displayed right underneath the navigation bar instead?

Many Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/QDpRL/5/

Comment: Your question is a little vague, please clarify and provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) if possible

Comment: Okay. I am new and will try jsFiddle. Be right back.